# Exposing Bash Script in RASPI as REST Service

Tags: bash, rest, web-services, raspberry-pi

I want to expose bash script as web service which can be triggered via other nodes in the same network.

I don't want to make service accessible globally, but if I can trigger that from other raspi devices in the same network, that will work.

Can you please suggest some ways?

Also, that service should be running all the time. If any crash it should restart the raspi and trigger the sh again.

Comment: The question is too broad. Please add some additional information. What do your bash script do? What programming languages are you considering?

Comment: Also, you might get a better response to this question at https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Hi Robin, the script will start, stop or restart a particular service. So the main aim is to start/stop the service in the raspi from other device so I dont have to login to that raspi and manually trigger that.

Comment: Can't you just have the service be run when the Pi boots up?

Comment: no, actually I am using distcc and avahi and there is some logic and based on that I need to start and stop the service. even if the machine is up, I dont want that service to be running all the time. hence was planning for exposing as REST service.